# JCE Editor toolbar icons do not load properly

Tags: css, joomla, toolbar, joomla-content-editor

I have a Joomla! 3.3.3  and I'm using JCE. My problem is that the editor is not showing the icons of the buttons on the toolbar. Using Firebug, I realized it was a problem in the path of the css of all themes.

[image]

[image]

In this case, I'm using Classic. The css that appears in of the Firebug code is:

```
.classicSkin .mceIcon {
   background: url("/campusbaixada/web/sites/dev01.unifesp.br/components/com_jce/editor/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/icons.gif") in the repeat scroll 20px 20px RGBA (0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

If I change to:

```
.classicSkin .mceIcon {
   background: url ("/ components / com_jce / editor / tiny_mce / themes / advanced / img / icons.gif") no-repeat scroll 20px 20px rgba (0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

then part of the toolbar will reappear.

So I'm going in the JCE folder on the server (components / com_jce / editor / tiny_mce / themes / advanced / skins / classic) and change the code for the

```
.classicSkin .mceIcon {
   background: url (img ../../ / icons.gif) no-repeat 20px 20px;
}
```

to

```
.classicSkin .mceIcon {background: url (/components/com_jce/editor/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/icons.gif) no-repeat 20px 20px;}
```

Now my questions:

I tried to leave it fixed at a default css file of my template because every time I update the component, it loses my settings, but could not make it work.

On their forum, besides not having this problem, I have to pay to be able to post the doubts ... can anyone help me?

Comment: [joomla.se] Stack Exchange was available since April 29th, 2014.  Please post all of your Joomla questions there to help that community grow and to receive support from a community with a more intimate knowledge of the CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following workaround worked for me: Log into the Administrator.  Go to Components -> JCE Editor -> Global Configuration.  Set "Compress CSS" to No and click Save.